# Feedback to "We really like this job for you" emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I do sometimes receive jobs emails from SO (it's OK, I'm looking for a job), however, some of the jobs that "you really like for me" are ***very*** not for me. They have tags of technologies and frameworks that I need to Google to know what they are, and they are for senior engineer positions. In fact, the only thing that these emails have that are related to me is that the location is near where I am. Note that I don't even care about moving, so even this is not what I want!

It would be nice to give feedback on these emails, to basically tell the algorithm: Nope, you are wrong, I don't like this job.

Comment: interesting... perhaps one thing they can do is to match the jobs with the tags associated to the questions we have already answered.

Comment: The location seems buggy as well. I changed my location months ago (unless there are multiple settings for this) but still see jobs around my old location, 8000 km away...

Comment: Same here exactly.

Comment: "These *are* the jobs you are looking for..." Obi-Wan

Comment: @JeffC "I am now a back end web-developer in Django"

Comment: same - StackOverflow Jobs is catered very heavily towards senior engineers. I guess there's not much money in connecting jobs for junior engineers with 1 internship like me :P

Comment: congrats. Atleast SO thinks you are Senior SE

Comment: @i-- should I add that to my CV? :P It is not useful for anything really.

Comment: I'm a very experienced senior-level software engineer and the job emails I get from SO are so...wrong.  It would be good to be able to vote on these so that your algorithm can learn what I would really be interested in.

Comment: @germanio - also maybe match to tags that we follow without answering a lot/at all

Comment: Yea, this happens to me at times with those emails.

Comment: I have 46 years experience and I get mail about mid-level jobs. No senior bias evident there :-|

Comment: I've had the same experience. "We like this job for you" only that it requires a degree and 3+ years of experience in something i've never even heard of.

Comment: @EJP One would expect that from anyone, a user with your rep would be the one getting the right job ads. Because the large amount of data supporting your expertise.

Comment: @Matt that sounds good too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's, ehm, embarassing...

Let me go into details.

---

### What happened?

Digging into your particular case, I discovered that we weren't taking into account your Stack Overflow question view history to determine job recommendations.

Put simply, if you look at a lot of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions, we weren't taking that into account, even though that's a pretty important piece of information.

This bug was introduced 17 days ago, and affected, well, all the areas which leverage our job matching algorithm: job search, emails, job recommendations on your profile, etc...

All the other criteria that help us select job matches were applied correctly, including geographic location, and [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

Only the Stack Overflow tag views were ignored, and (ironically) only for registered users. Stack Overflow tag views are the most important criteria for selecting job matches, so this was a pretty serious bug.

### What caused the bug?

The source of the bug was a recent refactor (by yours truly) which caused the `AccountId` property not to be set on `InterestingJobsRequest` instances.

As a result, the Stack Overflow question history (tag views) for the account was not fetched from [Providence](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/), so it stopped having any effect on the matching algorithm.

### Fix it (thrice)

The bug has been resolved, and a unit test has been added to make sure this specific problem doesn't reoccur.

I'm also working on an additional integration test which should further ensure this bug won't resurrect.

### "We really like this job for you" emails

We've received a lot of feedback about this email (thank you for your report!) and we're currently discussing and experimenting with several options to make sure we email you relevant jobs.

Those include:

- Stricter eligibility criteria for recipients of the email, i.e. only email users who are active or passive job seekers, and only if we know enough about them to surface good job recommendations.
- Stricter job selection: look at additional features of the jobs, and ensure those features match the user's interests. Specifically, look at the jobs' title and developer role (full stack, mobile, ...)
- New machine learning approaches: initiate discovery on new classification algorithms.

Comment: Wow I found a bug in SO! do I get a price? :P Nah, really, thanks for looking into this and fixing it! props to the fast response! keep up with the good job!

Comment: I'll forward to seeing this in the future.  I'd still like a vote button on the SO "we really like this job for you" emails.  The suggestions are embarrasingly bad.