# Feedback about "We like this job for you" email

Tags: discussion, email, stack-overflow-jobs

If you check the tech I answer questions on, it's not Java, C++, go, C, or python. I've also never been a "backend developer". I've dabbled, but I don't have enough experience with it to take it. This job is so mismatched, I've already unsubscribed from these emails as they'll probably be worthless.

> Job type: Permanent
>   Experience level: Mid-Level
>   Role: Backend Developer
>   Industry: Software Development, Software Development / Engineering, Web Development
>   Company size: 501-1,000
>   Company type: Private
>   Technologies: java c++ go c python

Comment: Why the f*ck do they use so many language tags? Also, if you don't answer C questions why is [tag:c] in your top 5 tags?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Same way I got a C++ badge without ever using C++ much, answering questions that people tagged incorrectly. Newbies have this _very_ nasty habit of adding C to C++, C#, Objective C, etc - and then it somehow never gets edited out. Well, it's _mostly_ inexperienced folks, some do it to get questions more instant visibility (which usually ends up in just summoning 50+ angry C programmers).

Comment: @StephenLeppik probably this question I asked. Which honestly was something interesting I happened across, and just asked over here since it wasn't mentioned anywhere else on the site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816659/can-printf-get-replaced-by-puts-automatically-in-a-c-program

Comment: I enjoy the senior positions I get as a dev with less than 2 years experience. Yeah, I'm sure these 1000 employee companies will accept someone who graduated two years ago as their CTO; I'll get right on that application.

Comment: @TimPost, If you are going to answer a question, it's somewhat incumbent upon you to clean up the question, at least such that it has the appropriate tags. The fact that a question you've answered has inappropriate tags is at least partially, if not significantly, your own responsibility. There's even a [series of badges](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for making such edits: Explainer, Refiner, [Illuminator](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370). Obviously, there are times when making such an edit is inappropriate (invalidates another answer), but that should be rare.

Comment: I suspect the email routine just grabs the top X jobs for everyone every week without sufficiently validating the quality of the matches. I was going to try blacklisting some tags / geographic areas to see if the quality of email matches improved - but then I realized I don't actually want job emails from SE anyways and wasn't curious enough to do QC on their behalf, so I just turned it off in my settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["We really like this job for you" annoying emails](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354588/we-really-like-this-job-for-you-annoying-emails) and also [Feedback to “We really like this job for you” emails](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356480/feedback-to-we-really-like-this-job-for-you-emails?rq=1)

Comment: I've gotten "we like this job for you" emails for senior positions requiring a degree I do not have working with languages I've never even touched before :p

Comment: I almost exclusively answer in the Perl tag, and there are hardly ever any jobs in Germany with Perl. Every time I get this email, it's for Berlin jobs, and just lists any of them. Frontend, backend, sysadmins, you name it. Completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) is the best way ensure you receive relevant job recommendations.

[Here is more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358454/5516513) on the recent changes we've made to improve job recommendations.